# do I need to delete photos uploaded with load_image_file (MS face_recognition API)

Tags: face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am testing Microsoft Face Recognition API (python).

I have a few photos on my HDD, and I analyse those images using:

```
CF.face.detect('PATH_TO_FILE')
CF.face.verify(face_1['faceId'], face_2['faceId'])
```

My question is: 
Are the images I uploaded saved on my account (I know they might be used to further improve MS services)?
Can (and how) I delete them?

Thanks, 
Shimi

Answer (score 0):

The Face API doesn’t currently offer a feature that allows images to be persisted in the service. 
Image file is not stored: When you upload image files to the Face API Service, the uploaded image files are not stored anywhere within our service.
Data that is stored: The Face API uses the uploaded image to generate a  ‘feature representation’ of the face in the image. This is an array of float numbers which, on their own, are meaningless. The feature representation is stored. 
And in your case, since you're using the faceId - The faceId produced by 'Detect' will expire 24 hours after the detection call.